# JqGrid Column Reorder not working with grouped header

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Column reordering works great with JQGrid with sortable: true. Now that I have grouped the header it has stopped working. How can I get the column reordering work with the grouped header. Here is the sample code

```
<script>
var mydata = [
    { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" }

    ];
function drawGrid() {
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
        sortable: true,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55 },
                    { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90 },
                    { name: 'name', index: 'name asc, invdate', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right" },
                    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right" },
                    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right" },
                    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
                ],

        sortname: 'invdate',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "Column Reordering Example"

    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    drawGrid();
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle: false,
        groupHeaders: [
                        { startColumnName: 'amount', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<em>Financial</em>' },
                      ]
    });
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
        jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but many features of jqGrid has the corresponding limitations. You can't use `sortable: true` or [columnsChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) together with [Header grouping](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#header_grouping) (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agroupingheadar#limitations))

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/620/

Please take a look the code does work as it should: i.e. set group happened fine and the sorting as well.

Hope this helps and let me know if I missed anything!

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drawGrid();
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle: false,
        groupHeaders: [
            {
            startColumnName: 'amount',
            numberOfColumns: 2,
            titleText: '<em>Financial</em>'},
            ]
    });
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);

});
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. By sortable:true I meant the reordering of the column and not sorting the column. As Oleg points me to the documentation it seems that this is not possible.